# jQuery .animate() - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with how I'm using the `.animate()` function?

This is my code:

```js
var hei = $("#myDiv").css("height");
hei += 5;
hei *= -1;
var ght = "px"
var height = hei + ght

function slidedown1() {
  $("#myDiv").css("top", height);
  $("#myDiv").css("display", "block");
  $("#myDiv").animate({
    top: '0px'
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      $("#myDiv").animate({
        top: height
      }, 1000);
      $("#myDiv").css("display", "none");
    }, 15000)
}
```

```html
<head> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>

<body onload="slidedown1()">
  <div id="myDiv" style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;border-radius:2px;position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px">
    Lorem ipsum and so on
    </div>
  </body>
```

What it should do is set a variable to get a `div`'s height, add 5, multiply by -1, and add 'px' at the end. Then it should set that div to go upwards by that number from the top of the page, make it's css `display:block;` instead of `display:none;`, and animate it down to where it's supposed to be. Then after 15 seconds, it should return the div upwards and set the `display` back to `none`.

For some reason `.animate()` isn't working, but everything else is.

Comment: So you want the div to start off screen and then come down from the top to its original position?

Answer (score 3):

This sets `hei` to  `100px`:

```
var hei = $("#myDiv").css("height")
```

This changes it to `100px5`:

```
hei + = 5;
```

This attempts to multiply `100px5` by -1, returning `NaN`:

```
hei * = -1;
```

To fix this, use **[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** on the first line:

```
var hei = parseInt($("#myDiv").css("height"), 10);
```

Note that you don't need to add `px` to that – `px` is the default unit for jQuery `css()` and `animate()` functions.

**Snippet**

```js
var hei = parseInt($("#myDiv").css("height"), 10);
hei += 5;
hei *= -1;
var ght = "px"
var height = hei + ght

function slidedown1() {
  $("#myDiv").css("top", height);
  $("#myDiv").css("display", "block");
  $("#myDiv").animate({
    top: '0'
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      $("#myDiv").animate({
        top: height
      }, 1000);
      $("#myDiv").css("display", "none");
    }, 15000)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>

<body onload="slidedown1()">
  <div id="myDiv" style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;border-radius:2px;position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px">
    Lorem ipsum and so on
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be that you need to parse the selected `height`. And if you are using jQuery, that is the way to trigger `onload` event:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div id="myDiv" style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;border-radius:2px;position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px">
    Lorem ipsum and so on
    </div>
  </body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var hei = parseInt($("#myDiv").css("height"));
    hei += 5;
    hei *= -1;
    var ght = "px";
    var height = hei + ght;

    function slidedown1() {
      $("#myDiv").css("top", height);
      $("#myDiv").css("display", "block");
      $("#myDiv").animate({
        top: '0px'
      }, 1000);
      setTimeout(
        function() {
          $("#myDiv").animate({
            top: height
          }, 1000);
          $("#myDiv").css("display", "none");
        }, 15000);
    }

    slidedown1();

});
```

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/tmqu09ru/